# Which one to choose execlp over system for launching ps? Why?

Tags: exec, system-calls

I am newbie learning linux pragramming.

Following is the code that I have written to launch a process showing Process status.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf(“This is the launch of ps with system command\n”);
  system(“ps ax”);

  exit(0);
}
```

And then I did the same thing with execlp:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf(“This is the launch of ps with execlp command\n”);
  execlp(“ps”, “ps”, “ax”, 0);

  exit(0);
}
```

How does the two differ?
Only thing that I could think about is that the `system()` invokes the desired
program using a shell. Does this make `system()` use inefficient?

I believe that here (when I use `system()`), a shell is started before the program is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you got it right about `exec` family of calls being efficient way to launch a process or an process as an application.

When we use the `system()` call, the program has to wait until the process started by the
call to system finishes, you can’t get on with other tasks.
And, The call to system returns as soon as the shell command finishes. Because it’s a
request to run a program in the background, the shell returns as soon as the `ps` program is started, Just the same thing happen as when you type `$ ps ax` on your shell.

Whereas, the `exec()` family is efficient in a manner that they start processes and present program arguments. An `exec` function replaces the current process
with a new process specified by the path or file argument. You can literlly use `exec()` functions to switch the execution of your program from one to another.

This makes the `exec()` functions more efficient than `system()` because the original program will no longer be running after the new one is started.